# How to execute a task/command right after the project is loaded in sbt shell

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I would like to execute a task/command every time I enter the sbt shell. Is there any init-task or init-command setting? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use `*.sbt` or `*.scala` to define you sbt project?
In case of scala files it's supposed to be simple. Basically during sbt startup all code in scala classes is compiled and executed. So basically what can you do is to define command(function) you want to execute directly inside `class/object` where your project is defined.

Option 2. Based on docs.

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/faq.html#how-can-i-take-action-when-the-project-is-loaded-or-unloaded
Pay attention on `onLoad` setting key.

Comment: I am using *.scala file. Option 1 is not going to work since I need the logger in the code.  onLoad setting key does the job. thank you.